# React native invariant violation error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, render

I want to implement redux in my react-native app, I imported provider in App.js but when I wrap App content inside `<Provider store={store}></Provider>` it gives me this error:

`Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with .... object with keys {$$typeof, type, key, ref, props, _owner, _store}).`

I know that I can't render object in return method but what I am supposed to do, how to connect app to redux ?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

// import reducer from './reducers/index';

import TabNavigation from './navigation/TabNavigation';
import StackNavigation from './navigation/StackNavigation';

//const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));

export default class App extends React.Component{

  render() {
    return (
    //<Provider store={store}>
        <TabNavigation />
      //</Provider>
      );
  }
}
```

It's commented out now and it works, if I uncomment it it gives the error...

Answer (score 0):

I see something is wrong on this line.

//const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));

The second parameter is the initial state and you are passing middleware there. See if this can solve it.

If that does not solve it, then the problem would be in the Component TavNavigation is rendering.

Comment: The same result...I guess it would give me an error always if the problem is navigation, not just when I include provider.. Navigation just export default `createBottomTabNavigation({ ...})`

Comment: Not sure why it is happening :( Can you try wrapping the TabNavigation inside a **View** ?

Comment: It's not problem in App.js, seems it's problem with Register component which I connected to redux, there is a problem..

Comment: I think I solved it, seems like I needed to get state property instead of state in my global one..

Comment: Wrong, it's problem with importing firebase, really weird, can't solve it, when I remove firebase import like this `import * as firebase from 'firebase';` it works, I tried `import firebase from 'firebase'` and many other but doesn't work..